# Knockout.js: Access submodel properties

Tags: knockout.js

This is my fiddle link. Please help me.
http://jsfiddle.net/KLXN5/

```
var Person = function(first, last)
{
    var self = this;

    this.FirstName = first;

    this.Children = ko.observable(new Children(last));

}
```

I need to access `Children.LastName` property.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `with` to set context which will allow access *Children*:

```
<div data-bind="text: FirstName"></div>

<div data-bind="with: Children">
    <div data-bind="text: LastName"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know it should be simple. Yes it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry! i dont have the reputation to mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to checkout my binding conventions library, its a convention over configuration library for KO and takes away most headaches with bindings and contexts,

For your example

http://jsfiddle.net/KLXN5/1/

```
<div>
<div data-name="FirstName"></div>
<div data-name="Children.LastName"></div>

</div>

If you have more than one property you want to access its better todo

<div>
   <div data-name="Children">
       <div data-name="LastName"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/wiki

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing this from inside Person try something like this.

```
//To Access the current value
var x = this.Children().LastName()

//To edit the current value
this.Children().LastName("Some new value")
```